# redirect_to doesn't redirect to specified path (jQueryMobile / Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I call redirect_to in this def create:

```
class M::TodosController < ApplicationController
  layout 'm/application'

  def create
    @todo = @goal.todos.build(params[:todo])
     ...
    puts "XXXXX => " +  m_goal_todo_path(@goal, @todo)
    redirect_to m_goal_todo_path(@goal, @todo)
  end
...
```

I check routes => rake routes:

```
m_goal_todo GET    /m/goals/:goal_id/todos/:id(.:format)                          m/todos#show
```

In my log:

```
XXXXX => /m/goals/46/todos/358


Started POST "/m/goals/46/todos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-13 13:47:14 +0900
Processing by M::TodosController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"todo"=>{"content"=>"23"}, "goal_id"=>"46"}
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "authentication_tokens" WHERE (logged_in_until < '2014-03-13 13:47:14.014105')
  AuthenticationToken Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "authentication_tokens".* FROM "authentication_tokens" WHERE "authentication_tokens"."token" = '5aTg7cWiDXAJj8IHd2NePqat1fNaXc0Nu9kAtS2PF6N8TDR8T5IeZYUZsT4Iy7dkuyy5FkmO_qyDuXX8' LIMIT 1
...
```

& still It doesn't redirect to -> /m/goals/46/todos/358 it goest to /m/goals/46/

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 & jQueryMobile

+++ UPDATE +++

Tried

```
def create
  @todo = @goal.todos.build(params[:todo])
   ...
   puts "XXXXX => " +  m_goal_todo_path(@goal, @todo)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to m_goal_todo_path(@goal, @todo)}
   end
end
```

Getting the same behavior.

Also, I tried disabling Ajax by adding rel="external", nothings changes

```
<a href="#" class="add center" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" rel="external">やるべきことを追加</a>
```

+++ UPDATE 2 +++

new.html.erb

```
<div class="center">
  <a href="#" class="add center" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-mini="    true" data-inline="true" data-ajax="false">やるべきことを追加</a>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
  $(document).on('click', '.todos_new_page .add', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var goalId = $this.closest('.todos_new_page').data('goal-id');
    var $content = $this.closest('[data-role=content]').find('#content');
    if ( $content.val() == "") {
      alert("記入して下さい");
      return false;
    }
    var content = $content.val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/m/goals/' + goalId + '/todos',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {todo: {content: content}},
      error: defaultAjaxError
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuz I have this peace of code -> `data-rel="back"` I was redirected to `/m/goals/46/todos/358`

So, I deleted it :) & add ⬇ to my ajax call

```
success: function(link) {
    $.mobile.changePage('/m/'+link.go);
  }
```

Where link.go -> `render "/m/goals/_update_goal_html", json: { go: "/goals/" + @goal.id.to_s + "/todos/" + @todo.id.to_s}`

Works fine :)

Babasaheb Gosavi, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In Jquery mobile views are not changing as it is totally Ajax based. you need to specify something like this

```
def create
  @todo = @goal.todos.build(params[:todo])
   ...
   puts "XXXXX => " +  m_goal_todo_path(@goal, @todo)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to m_goal_todo_path(@goal, @todo)}
   end
end
```

Or you need to disable Ajax for form from where create action is called using data-ajax = "false"

Comment: Thank you for your response.
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to m_goal_todo_path(@goal, @todo)}
   end
Getting the same behavior.

I tried disabling Ajax by adding rel="external", still having the same behavior
  <a href="#" class="add center" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" rel="external">やるべきことを追加</a>

Comment: You need to specify data-ajax = "false" in <a> tag

Comment: can you give me the code where you used this so that I can check

Comment: I just updated. Please, check +++ UPDATE 2 +++. Let me know if you need more info.